# Find the input of the instrument if output is a boxcar function.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, signal-processing

Impulse response of an instrument h(t) is given by $h(t)= 3*exp(-3*t)$ for $t>=0$. Find the input of the instrument if output is a boxcar function $f(t)= 3$, $0=<t=<2$ and $0$, otherwise.

Comment: What is the model that makes $h$ and $f$ have something to do with each other? And what are your thoughts on how to approach the question?

Comment: The problem can be thought as- convolution of input (say g(t)) and impulse response functions yields a constant function f(t). I can proceed like- FT(g)*FT(h)=FT(f). But, I have problem with computing the FT of f(t)=3

Comment: Isn't that something like $\hat f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{ikt}dt = \int_0^2 3e^{ikt}dt = \frac{3}{ik}(e^{2it}-1)$? (your definition of FT may garnish it with some other constants somewhere).